# How to Send the Current Thread to Sleep

Tags: android

```
Thread thred = new Thread();
        thred.run();


    public void run() {
        while (true)
        {

       try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sleep Over", 100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sleep NOT Over", 100);
            }
        }
```

This code don't work

Comment: My programm also dont accsess the run()

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error, what's the error? When implementing the `run()` method of a Thread, you call `start()`, not `run()`.

Comment: Not only that... you are creating an empty Thread object and calling the run method of that object. Meaning, the run method you implemented is not part of that thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread thred = new Thread()
{ 


    public void run() {
        while (true)
        {

         try {
                sleep(500);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sleep Over", 100);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sleep NOT Over", 100);
             }
        }
    }
};
thred.start();
```

You need to call the sleep method of the current thread Thread.sleep will call the static sleep method. You need to make sure you are overriding the run method of the thread class with your own run method and then calling thread.start not run.